# Why has my question been deleted?

Tags: discussion, delete

I [posted a question](//tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515597) and received an answer. Shortly after that the entire post (question and answer) was deleted. Why is that?

Additionally, why was my reputation reduced from 433 to 399?

Comment: There is a mod comment you should have seen: concern over the text and possible copyright issues

Answer (score 9):

The reasoning of one of our moderators why it was deleted was given in a comment:

> I am deleting this questions since it contains content (copy of a letter) that seems to be without a license to be published. The issue has been solved, and it was about replicating and not like a common TeX problem/question, so it's probably not useful for others in the public anyway.

Comment: how do I object to this deletion

Comment: @jsbibra deleting the answer was appropriate. You posted a letter containing personal data (name, phone number, address, ... ) from other people. That is not ok. Darken such text before uploading an image.

Comment: @jsbibra you did already by asking this question. The usual procedure to reopen your question would be to find enough people with sufficient reputation to vote to reopen/undelete it, but in this case I don't think anyone would (see Ulrike's comment above mine).